# how can i set dynamic proxy and useragent with phnomatjs or other driver in scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm learning scrapy now. I want use selenium in scrapy. I need help in selenium.

I want to set different user-agent and proxy in different request but in my early selenium usage I can set these things before launch a driver, after that , I can't change it. Io I want to know how can I set these dynamic without re-launch the driver.

I had try below codes:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('javascript.enabled', False)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http', ip.split(':')[0])
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', int(ip.split(':')[1]))  # int
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', ip.split(':')[0])
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', int(ip.split(':')[1]))
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

After that I can't change the ip proxy without re-launch the driver.

Comment: finally i found the solution, i just made it via js.